# Powershell setting EnvironmentVariable works in ISE but not Console

Tags: powershell

I have an odd Powershell behavior i wish to understand.

If i set a permanent Environment Variable and start a process like the following

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('FOO','BAR','User')
Start-Process notepad
```

This works as expected in ISE Editor and if i type it after one other in the Console. However if i run it as a *.\script.ps1* Script from the Console the *Start-Process* will ignore the new or the changed Environment Variable. Even the Environment Variable is properly set before *Start-Process* is executed. I tested this by adding *Sleep* and checking the Environment Variable Dialogue manually. If the script is run a second time the Process will read the Environment Variable as expected since it has been changed before already.

Why is the Console behavior not the same as in ISE in this case?

I already tried if this has to do with specific Assemblies that are loaded in ISE and not the Console but it does not seam so.
I also tried to run as *STA* but it did not work either.

Comment: Did you try dot-sourcing the script file `powershell.exe . .\.script.ps1` or setting the environment variable to use the `Machine` target location?

Comment: @Theo using `Machine` as target location worked. However this requires me to run the console as admin which is not always optimal. Would it be save to say that the application is checking `Machine` prior to `User` Environment Variables!? But it's kinda beyond me how this could break the script. I also tested to run the `*.ps1` script (with `User` Variable) from _cmd_ but also no luck. Neither worked the dot-sourcing (with `User` Variable). Another test i did is with the PS2EXE wrapper and there neither `User` or `Machine` worked. My brain is fried now.

Comment: Whether you target `User` or `Machine` on _setting_ doesn't make a difference; whether you start a new process _as admin_ or not makes the difference - please see my answer, in particular the footnote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Note: This answer is specific to *Windows*, because [`System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable) only supports modifying *persistent* environment-variable definitions (via target scopes `User` and `Machine`) there. The fundamentals of how PowerShell determines a child process' environment apply on Unix-like platforms too, however.</sup>

**`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` with a target-scope [`System.EnvironmentVariableTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.EnvironmentVariableTarget) argument of `User` or `Machine` *only* updates the *persistent* environment-variable definitions *in the registry* - it doesn't also update the *current* process's *in-memory* variables**.

By contrast, target `Process` updates *only* the *current* process' variables *non-persistently*.
As such, `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('FOO','BAR','Process')` is the equivalent of `$env:FOO = 'BAR'`

**[`Start-Process`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) by default uses the *current* process's environment variables<sup>[1]</sup> and therefore doesn't see variables (yet) that were created or updated by targeting the `User` or `Machine` scopes *in the same process*.**<sup>[2]</sup>

`Start-Process`'s `-UseNewEnvironment` parameter is *in principle* designed to do what you want: it is meant to start the new process with environment-variable values *read from the registry*, ignoring the calling process' values - however, this feature is *broken* as of PowerShell [Core] v7.0 - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4671).

The **workaround** is to *also* define the new variable in the *current* process:

```
# Update both the registry and the current process.
foreach ($targetScope in 'User', 'Process') {
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('FOO', 'BAR', $targetScope)
}

# Start a new process with the new value in effect.
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait powershell '-c \"`$env:FOO is: $env:FOO\"'
```

Note that - unlike what `-UseNewEnvironment` *should* do - this makes the new process inherit all *process-only* (in-memory) environment variables / values too.

---

<sup>[1] A process is given a block of environment variables on startup, often a *copy* of the *parent process's* block (as PowerShell itself does by default when creating child processes). That startup block may or may not reflect the then-current registry definitions. In-process modifications of the environment block are lost when the process terminates, unless they are explicitly persisted, such as with `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()`  and target scopes `User` or `Machine`. As all programs that modify the persistently defined environment variables should do, `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` broadcasts Windows message `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` as a notification of the change, but few programs are designed to listen to it and therefore few update their in-process environment variables in response (which isn't appropriate for all programs).</sup>

<sup>[2] However, if you start the new process *as an administrator* with `-Verb RunAs` (Windows-only) *using the current user's credentials*, the new process *will* see the new/updated definitions, because it then does *not* use the current process' environment variables and instead reads the then-current definitions from the registry.</sup>

Comment: Setting the `User` and `Process` Environment Variable did the trick. Thanks to making sense to the digital world to me once again. To clarify, the current Powershell process is storing all Environment Variables in memory at the start and any process launched from the Console will be based on them instead of the updated registry. That is why i was able to check the Environment Dialogue manually and see the updated entry but it did not affect the application since the process was started from the console that was still holding the old Environment Variables in memory. Is that correct?

Comment: @secondplace, correct; please see the new footnote I've just added to the answer.